# After I limit letters enter in the input, cannot backspace or type anything?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

click http://jsfiddle.net/qPvch/291/ to see result. I found this code in one of stackoverflow answers, I had edited it a little bit. I only want to limit the numbers of letter, I did it successfully, but after I reach the limit, I cannot backspace it or type anything. Help, appreciate.

```js
var maxWords = 3;
jQuery('#txt1').keypress(function() {
    var $this, wordcount;
    $this = $(this);
    wordcount = $this.val().length;
    if (wordcount > maxWords) {
        return false;
    } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Max 3 letters
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
```

Comment: why not just do it with html: `maxlength="3"`

Comment: The question is, why not just `<input type="text" maxlength="3" />`, no javascript needed ?

Comment: its working fine for me. on Chrome

Comment: backspace is a keypress, detected there are already 3 so no work - think about it :-)

Comment: @CodeGodie chrome is *special* but not in a good way

Comment: Thank you! You clear my mind, Lol, I had not think about that. I had focus on study jquery a lot these day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dagon haha, good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test to see what was entered, e.g. whether it is a character. For example:

```
var maxWords = 2;
jQuery('#txt1').keypress(function(e) {
    var $this, wordcount;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(code)
    $this = $(this);
    wordcount = $this.val().length;
    if (wordcount > maxWords  && char.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Get the keycode, convert it to a character and then test it against all letters (case insensitive). You could adnust the match string depending on your needs.

See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/q4pmz9j1/)